# Slider Stretches Displays Correctly in Chrome but Not Firefox

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome, firefox

https://salty-beyond-6727-967.herokuapp.com/

This is a link to the QA copy of a homepage I'm working on.

I used a slider and it works in Chrome(and even IE) but not in Firefox, it gets cut off and offset to the right.

I've tried HTML validating my code, checking for empty divs, moving the content container around and just can't seem to fix this problem. If anyone knows of a solution or can point me in the right direction I would be very grateful!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Header and navigation is getting floated in your code. if you add **clear:both** before `<div class="slider-inner">.. </div>` this will be solved

or

```
<div class="clear"></div>
<div class="slider-inner">
.
.
.
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.clear{    
clear:both
}
```

Comment: thanks this works and so does float left but i think i will go with this fix. Is there any reason why firefox needs this extra line as opposed to chrome and IE rendering properly without it?

Answer (score 0):

target the below div which is inside the `<div class="slider-inner">` and, make it absolute positioned. this will work..

```
<div id="da-slider" class="da-slider">
```

CSS

```
div.da-slider{
   position: absolute;
}
```

Comment: appreciate the two cents, but seems like the slider plugin inherits a position relative already.

Answer (score 0):

Simpler solution may be adding `Float:Left` to .da-slider class
`.da-slider{Float:left}`. If you don't want to edit the slider class inherit it from parent class .slider-inner.

Comment: thank you. this works, i was always warned about using floats though. could you see any case where using a float might cause problems with the header or body later?